# Creating an Associative array out of groups and members

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically creating/inserting into an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447385/dynamically-creating-inserting-into-an-associative-array-in-php)

I have the following entries generated in a for loop.

```
CN=Group01,CN=Users,DC=cnn,DC=local - abc@xyz.net
CN=Group04,CN=Users,DC=cnn,DC=local - def@xyz.net
CN=Group02,CN=Users,DC=cnn,DC=local - mlb@xyz.net
CN=Group04,CN=Users,DC=cnn,DC=local - rst@xyz.net
```

How can I arrange them in an associative array, so, it looks like this:

```
Array 
(
  [Group01] => ([0]=>abc@xyz.net),
  [Group02] => ([0]=>mlb@xyz.net),
  [Group04] => (
                [0]=>def@xyz.net, 
                [1]=>rst.net
               )
)
```

The associative array does not need to have `CN=Users, DC=cnn, DC=local` string.

The code I have in the for loop is:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $entries["count"]; $i++)
{
   if (isset($entries[$i]["mail"][0]) && isset($entries[$i]["memberof"][0]))
   {
       echo $entries[$i]["memberof"][0]." - ".$entries[$i]["mail"][0]."<br />";
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: When you generate those entries in your for loop, why dont you create the associative array as well?

Comment: I plan to do it that way.. just not sure how..

Comment: Hey. It's not a duplicate of that.. It's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$info = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  $parts = explode(',', $entry);
  $groupName = substr($parts[0], 3);
  $emailParts = explode(' - ', $parts[3]);
  $email = $emailParts[1];
  $info[$groupName][] = $email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$records = file('yourfile.csv');
$grpUsrArr = array();
foreach( $records as $lineNo => $record );
{
    $data    = explode( ',', $record );
    $grpName = explode( '=', $data[0] );
    $usrName = explode( ' - ', $data[3] );
    $grpUsr[end( $grpName )][]=end( $usrName );
}
```