# How To Get Data from JSON Into Unordered List?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file that contain this:

```
"Menus": [{
    "MenuId": "1",
    "MenuName": "Perencanaan dan Pengadaan",
    "MenuParent": "",
    "MenuLink": ""
}, {
    "MenuId": "1-1",
    "MenuName": "RKA / DPA",
    "MenuParent": "1",
    "MenuLink": ""
}, {
    "MenuId": "1-1-1",
    "MenuName": "Daftar RKA / DPA",
    "MenuParent": "1-1",
    "MenuLink": "rkbu"
},
```

I want to put that data into unordered list dynamically. So the output I want is like this (with 3 level list):

```
Perencanaan dan Pengadaan
    RKA / DPA
        Daftar RKA / DPA
```

I have tried this code:

```
echo "<ul>";

foreach($get_data['Menus'] as $node){
    if(strlen($node['MenuId']) == 1){
        echo "<li>" . $node['MenuName'];
        echo "</li>";
    }
        echo "<ul>";
            if(strlen($node['MenuId']) == 3){
                echo "<li>".$node['MenuName']."</li>";
        }
                if(strlen($node['MenuId']) == 5){
                    echo "<ul>";
                        echo "<li>".$node['MenuName']."</li>";
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
    echo "</ul>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

But I find that it is not dynamic because it depends on string length. I've read that the best method is using recursive method. But I cannot find the recursive pattern of my JSON file. Can anybody help me find the solution? Thanks

Comment: well if you'll have 100 nodes it will be |{1-1-1....-1}|=100?

Comment: ya @DanielKrom that is my problem here. That why I say it can be done with recursive method. But I cannot find the recursive pattern of my JSON file. I really need the pattern.

Comment: You need recursion to do that..

Comment: but what are you trying to do? just print it as a list? or? what's the regularity

Comment: no need recursion btw

Comment: KoKo I realize that. I just cannot find the recursive pattern.

@DanielKrom pardon my noob skill in programming. All I can do is what you've seen above. If it doesn't need recursion, so what is the another method I can approach?

Comment: oh I see, 1-1 is a sub menu of 1?

Comment: that's right @DanielKrom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to make recursive calls directly on your flat JSON data.

I suggest you first convert your flat data to a multidimensional array and afterwards recursively generate your menu.

I took parts of the code from here: [Dynamically creating/inserting into an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447385/dynamically-creating-inserting-into-an-associative-array-in-php)

```
$get_data = array(
    array(
        "MenuId" => "1",
        "MenuName" => "Perencanaan dan Pengadaan",
        "MenuParent" => "",
        "MenuLink" => ""
    ),
    array(
        "MenuId" => "1-1",
        "MenuName" => "RKA / DPA",
        "MenuParent" => "1",
        "MenuLink" => ""
    ),
    array(
        "MenuId" => "1-1-1",
        "MenuName" => "Daftar RKA / DPA",
        "MenuParent" => "1-1",
        "MenuLink" => "rkbu"
    )
);

function insert_into(&$array, array $keys, $value) {
     $last = array_pop($keys);       

     foreach($keys as $key) {
          if(!array_key_exists($key, $array) || 
              array_key_exists($key, $array) && !is_array($array[$key])) {
                  $array[$key]['items'] = array();

          }
          $array = &$array[$key]['items'];
     }
     $array[$last]['value'] = $value;
}

function create_menu($menuItems) {
    $content = '<ul>';
    foreach($menuItems as $item) {
        $content .= '<li>' . $item['value'];
        if(isset($item['items']) && count($item['items'])) {
            $content .= create_menu($item['items']);
        }
        $content .=  '</li>';
    }
    $content .= '</ul>';
    return $content;
}

$menuItems = array();
foreach($get_data as $item) {
    $levels = explode('-', $item['MenuId']);
    insert_into($menuItems, $levels, $item['MenuName']);
}
print_r($menuItems);
print create_menu($menuItems);
```

DEMO: http://3v4l.org/dRK4f

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [value] => Perencanaan dan Pengadaan 
        [items] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [value] => RKA / DPA 
                [items] => Array ( 
                    [1] => Array ( 
                        [value] => Daftar RKA / DPA 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)

<ul>
    <li>Perencanaan dan Pengadaan
        <ul>
            <li>RKA / DPA
                <ul>
                    <li>Daftar RKA / DPA</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey @Typoheads thanks for answering. I tried your code and find the solution. Awesome